# When was the last time the US Supreme Court limited rights with a decision?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court, human-rights, civil-rights, abortion

The Supreme Court has now [officially overruled Roe v Wade](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/06/24/roe-v-wade-overturned-by-supreme-court-ending-federal-abortion-rights.html), allowing states to restrict the rights of pregnant people. When was the last time the Supreme Court came to a decision that reduced the rights of the people? Would like both a small example (e.g. the classic "yelling fire in a movie theater") example and a more impactful one (such as Plessy v Ferguson).

Comment: This is going to be opinion based as you are going to have people disagreeing about the rulings and if they limit civil liberties or not.

Comment: I would downvote this loaded question if I could. Even though I'm pro-choice, you could easily argue that they were protecting pre-born people's right.

Comment: @JoeW I believe its fairly cut and dry - does a ruling allow people to do more things, or disallow them from doing something? For instance, Columbia v Heller (the 2008 gun rights case) or Citizens United v FEC may have produced decisions I don't support and one could argue they diminish the ability or influence of some, but they objectively made it possible for people to do things they couldn't necessarily legally do before

Comment: Most rulings do both, so it is hard to determine this.

Comment: I disagree, while you are saying that Roe v Wade is overturning civil liberties others are saying it upholds the civil liberties of unborn children. No matter how you look at it opposing sides of a ruling will see the results in a different light.

Comment: The subject of "right to abortion" falls under [tag:human-rights], but the question asks about "civil liberties of people". Freedom of speech is human rights, while *Plessy v Ferguson* was civil rights. I think some clarification is in order.

Comment: Would *reduce civil liberties of adults* provide sufficient differentiation?  I know, it sounds like it's tailored to avoid the unborn rights problems, but surely it is possible to phrase a question about curtailing a certain population's rights without shutting this down.  After all, this is the same supreme court that just judged a state's limitations on persons' right to carry guns couldn't be subject to too many limitations.  But yes, cleaning up of some terms is a good idea,

Comment: Also, while many may disagree with the terminology about rights, the [official dissent, page 4](https://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/22067295/dobbs-dissent.pdf) says: *Whatever the exact scope of the coming laws, one result
of today’s decision is certain: the curtailment of women’s
rights, and of their status as free and equal citizens.*  So the question's terms are not that far out from the terms used by the Court's dissenters themselves.  Still, if there a way to "unload" *this* question, that would be nice.

Comment: Wouldn't any case where a law that restricts civil liberties was ruled constitutional by the court count as "limiting civil liberties with a decision"?

Comment: I would narrow the question by asking when or whether the court has overruled itself on a liberty (or, narrower still, a personal liberty) that had been affirmed by an earlier decision.

Comment: One could also argue that the _Dobbs_ decision _restored_ the right of the people and their elected representatives to legislate on a controversial issue: "The Constitution says nothing about [abortion]. It neither forbids (as the pro-choice people claim) nor requires (as the pro-life people claim) restrictions upon it. For two centuries, laws in every state prohibited it, but now, under a living-Constitution theory, it cannot be prohibited. No use trying to persuade your fellow citizens one way or the other about the subject. It has been taken off the democratic stage....

Comment: ...And that is, of course, precisely what those who argued for Roe v. Wade desired to achieve. So don’t love the living Constitution because it will bring you flexibility and choice; it will bring you rigidity, which is precisely what it is designed for."  --Scalia, Antonin. Scalia Speaks: Reflections on Law, Faith, and Life Well Lived (p. 208). The Crown Publishing Group. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 2):

[As I had expected someone to have posted something by now, but I see nothing...] "Small examples" aren't going to be hard to find. [Morse v. Frederick (2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_v._Frederick) limited students' (1st amendment) rights to raise semi-funny "drug talk" posters on the opposite boardwalk of a school-sponsored event. (C-SPAN is usually as boring as it gets but [in this case](https://www.c-span.org/video/?318240-1/bong-hits-4-jesus) it's a lot more entertaining than Wikipedia's coverage. And "limited" here means that students can be [constitutionally] disciplined by the school, e.g. by suspension, for doing that.)

And since some commenters have dwelled on this: in US legal jargon "civil rights" and "civil liberties" are [not synonymous](https://www.findlaw.com/civilrights/civil-rights-overview/civil-rights-vs-civil-liberties.html). According to one viewpoint, free speech is a "civil liberty" but not a "civil right" (even though, ironically, some of the former are enumerated in the Bill of Rights.) In that vein, "civil rights" is a narrower notion that prohibits discrimination on a fairly narrow set of characteristics. And other than agreeing that they are not same notion, US legal compedia seem to even disagree what exactly "civil rights" are. On an alternative [view](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/civil_liberties), they include civil liberties.

Comment: Perhaps this isn't what the OP is looking for, but I would think the question is looking for "rights that were clearly and unambiguously recognized before, that were then revoked".  Would this fit that, or is this just a refinement/clarification of a right which had never been specified as protecting this particular form of action?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: the Q doesn't seem to me to make this narrowing that you see.

Comment: Out of curiousity, though, would this fit?

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: I see now that phoog has suggested in a comment (under the Q) that the Q be narrowed to the sense that you see.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy: Whether prior SCOTUS rulings created an expectation that that action would be constitutional is debatable. 
The ACLU [argued](http://www.aclu.org/pdfs/scotus/morse_v_frederick_respondentsbrief.pdf) (p.11) that it did so via [*Terminello*](https://www.mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/425/terminiello-v-chicago) (1949 -- a speech that resulted in a street riot was found protected) and [*Tinker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_v._Des_Moines_Independent_Community_School_District) (1969), although the supreme justices ultimately disagreed that *Tinker* could be interpreted...

Comment: that way (that case involved an arm-band promoting a more mainstream political cause in a school.) SCOTUS would later (2014) silently condone [by rejecting certiorari] a [9th circuit decsion](https://caselaw.findlaw.com/us-9th-circuit/1678148.html) siding with "a school [that] banned American flag apparel during a Cinco de Mayo celebration". The school argued that the ban was meant to prevent a gang fight on racial lines between Caucasian and Mexican students. So speech that may cause violent reactions is protected on the street but not by students in schools (or school-sponsored events).